# display a taxonomy terms as autocomplete using form API

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms

I am writing my own module. I want to display a taxonomy terms as a autocomplete field in my form using form API. How can I do that?

I am using Drupal7.

Comment: Have you read and tried to use [Form API reference section about autocomplete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#autocomplete_path)? What exactly is a problem?

Answer (score 8):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7, it can be done in 2 ways

- By using existing taxonomy field(like TAG field), for this example I'm using field_tag

  `$node=node_load($nid);
  $tags = array();
  foreach ($node->field_tags['und'] as $item) {
    $tags[$item['tid']] = isset($item['taxonomy_term']) ? $item['taxonomy_term'] : taxonomy_term_load($item['tid']);
  }
  $form['tags'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => taxonomy_implode_tags($tags),
    '#title' => 'Add Tags',
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'taxonomy/autocomplete/field_tags',
    '#maxlength' => 1024,
    '#element_validate' => array('taxonomy_autocomplete_validate'),page
  );`
- If you dont want to use any field then it can also be using custom autocomplete

  `//custom field
  $form['taxonomy_term_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'get_TAXONOMY_NAME/autocomplete',
  );
  //menu callback for autocomplete
  function HOOK_menu() {
    $items = array();
    ....
    $items['get_TAXONOMY_NAME/autocomplete/%'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'TAXONOMY_NAME_autocomplete_callback',
      'page arguments' => array(2),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ); 
    return $items;
  }
  //autocomplete callback function
  function TAXONOMY_NAME_autocomplete_callback($str = 0) {
    $matches = array();
    //vocabulary id
    $vid = 2;
    $result = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
      -> fields('t', array('tid', 'name'))
      -> condition('vid', $vid, '=')
      -> condition('name', $str.'%%', 'LIKE')
      -> range(0, 10)
      -> execute();
    foreach ($result as $term) {
      $matches[$term -> tid] = check_plain($term -> name);
    }
    drupal_json_output($matches);
  }`

  References : [Existing taxonomy field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15494/how-to-add-taxonomy-term-reference-field-in-a-custom-drupal-form) and [Custom autocomplete field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35645/how-to-add-exist-taxonomy-term-field-to-custom-form)

Answer (score 2):

```
$form['nameField'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#autocomplete_path'=>'example/autocomplete'
);

//HOOK_MENU
 function MODULENAME_menu() {
    $items['example/autocomplete'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'description' => '',
    'page callback' => 'example_autocomplete',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);

 function example_autocomplete() {
    $termes = taxonomy_vocabulary_get_names();
    $vocabulary = taxonomy_get_tree($termes['MACHINENAME']->vid);
    $list = array();
    foreach ($vocabulary as $taxonomy){
           $list[$taxonomy->tid] = $taxonomy->name;
    }
    print drupal_json_encode($list);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It is not working in my end.

Answer (score 1):

1) Custom Module name : common_operations

2)

```
/**
 *Implements hook_menu()
 */
function common_operations_menu() {
  $items['autocomplete/taxonomy'] = array(
    'title' => 'Menu Title',
    'description' => 'Menu description',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('common_operations_autocomplete_taxonomy_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['path/autocomplete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom Autocomplete',
    'page callback' => 'common_operations_custom_autocomplete',
    'access arguments' => array('access taxonomy autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
  *Defines autocomplete_taxonomy_form()
  *@param $form
  *@param &$form_state 
  *@return $form
  */
function common_operations_autocomplete_taxonomy_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['taxonomy'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Campus'),
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'path/autocomplete',
    '#maxlength' => 60,
    '#size' => 15,
    '#required' => 0,
  );

  //--------------------Others------------------

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Lets Go!'),
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 *Page callback for menu 'path/autocomplete'
 */
function common_operations_custom_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();
  $result = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd');
  $result->fields('ttd', array('tid', 'name'));
  $result->condition('vid', array(VID1, VID2,...), 'IN');
  $result->condition(db_or()->condition('ttd.name', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE'));
  $query = $result->execute();

  foreach ($query as $row) {     
    $matches[$row->tid] = $row->name; 
  }

  // Return the result to the form in json
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function common_operations_permission() {
  return array(
    'access taxonomy autocomplete' => array(
      'title' => t('Access Custom Taxonomy Autocomplete'),
        'description' => t('Access permission of Custom Taxonomy Autocomplete.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

3) Replace VID1, VID2, ... with the Vocabulary ID's

4) Clear drupal cache

5) Set Permission

6) Access path 'autocomplete/taxonomy' & try

Hope it helps