# Term Reference Autocomplete field that searches fields besides name

Tags: 7, entities, ajax

Is there any way to have a term reference autocomplete field search other fields than just the title?  In my case I have a organizations vocabulary with the taxonomy name and an acronym.  The main point of adding an acronym field is to stop users from putting in the acronym in place of the full organization name.

If I turned it into an entity reference field would, the autocomplete widget type allow me to do this?

Comment: so you want users to be able to autocomplete both name OR acronym in the same field?

Comment: I want to type the acronym and get the name as a result.

Comment: You can create a custom autocomplete that looks up the acronyms and submits the name upon selection. You can see more info in this [post]( http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78899/display-a-taxonomy-terms-as-autocomplete-using-form-api)

Comment: OK, that would be cool, I'll read up on that a little later.  To answer my second question on here, the entity reference field widget will allow you to use views for the autocomplete so you can get it to search and display whatever you want.  Unfortunately, at least on its own, it seems it can't create new taxonomy terms.

Comment: How will users create new terms, since you're using acronyms and full names? what if one user enters the acronym but another user enters the full name? this could quickly become unmanageable

Comment: We are just going to have to do periodic cleanups. Unless I find a better solution. It would be nice to have the autocomplete field for existing terms and an inline entity form for adding new items, but I have no idea whether that is possible/how to do that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've been able to determine, there is no way to modify what autocomplete searches in a term reference field, though if seems possible, even likely that there might be a module or hook that does this, I didn't find it.

To answer my second question, yes, making this an entity reference enables the use of views to power the autocomplete, at which point you can handle the formatting and search fields of the autocomplete.

Better answers on this are very welcome!